# github with Visual Studio 2013 - cannot pull because of uncommitted changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I am a single developer right now, but I do have a workplace, and I also do work at home. Github is pretty ideal for me because the goal is to track my code, but also just keep it in a good repository so I don't lose it. So here is my work process...

- Do work at home (`site a`)
- commit changes to github frequently

  - sometimes, this will be up to 20 commits in a day, depending on productivity. I commit 
    often.
- go to other work `site b` (usually office)
- clone repository at `site b`

  - this is done within visual studio, by going to `Team Explorer` -> `Projects` -> `Connect to Team Projects`, and then using `Clone` with the github repository URL.

[image: clone]

- redownload nuget packages, etc - resume work as normal at `site b` for the day

  - I perform frequent commits here, as well.
- return home (`site a`) and open up *Visual Studio 2013*
- open up the project I was working on
- go to `Team Explorer` -> `Unsynched Commits` and click `Pull`

[image: pull]

- sometimes it works
- sometimes, however, I receive the following error **and I have no idea why**

[image: error]

I would understand this if I had made edits to the current project **before** trying to pull - but I haven't. All I've done is loaded up Visual Studio. It says *"See the Output window for details"* but the Output window is completely blank - there are no details, and in this situation the only answer I've found is to delete the WHOLE project from my computer and clone the entire repository again.

Certainly this isn't right, I'm a complete newbie to git, and I have read the documentation over and over and this still makes no sense to me. Can anyone help shed some light on any of this?

Comment: Can you double check by execute command 'git status -s', for any changed pending to commit.

Comment: Where would I execute that, exactly? I've never used git through the command line as of yet, only the Visual Studio interface.

Comment: From project home directory

Comment: Just in a normal command line? Like `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Yes in command prompt

Comment: I merely get the result `'git' is not recognized as an internal or extranl command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Hey @VinitPrajapati, I just wanted to follow up on this and let you know that you helped me a lot too. I know that I cannot give you "answer" points, but if you would be so kind as to place your statements into an actual "response" to the question, I would gladly up vote it to give you appropriate credit, since I was able to accomplish other things with your suggestions and now can use `git` from my command line.

Comment: If you're interested in solving this from Visual Studio instead of passing from the command line, please upvote: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4576531-provide-stash-support-in-visual-studio-tools-for-g

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Before `pull`-ing you need to `stash` your uncommitted changes first. Visual Studio does not support full range of Git functionality yet, including `git stash`, so you have to do it through [command line](http://chocolatey.org/packages/git) or use something like [Source Tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) in addition to Visual Studio for such occasion. Run `git status -u` to see uncommitted changes and `git stash` to temporarily hide them before pulling/syncing. Once in a while Visual Studio will cache the status results and will get out of sync with reality, in this case kill Studio, delete `.git\ms-persist.xml` file and restart.

Comment: Alright... I am sorry to be ignorant, but what exactly do I need in order to do that? Trying to run these git commands in a command line isn't working, so I assume I need to install something. I did the `Install git 3rd party tools` through Visual Studio as it prompted me to, so I assumed it was downloading everything related to that.

Comment: Okay, following these instructions, I have added git to the "path"; http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/06/07/adding-git-to-windows-7-path/ - though I am on Windows 8, so I hope it works the same. Let me try what you have suggested and get back to you.

Comment: Aha! That worked! I had to go through `PowerShell`, a normal command line didn't seem to take it. Let me try this a few more times on some intentionally damaged tests in order to make sure I grasp it - then I'll accept the answer once stackoverflow's timer lets me.

Comment: @Ciel if you're not comfortable with command line or Chocolatey I would recommend installing Source Tree, it'll download it for you and will give you a nice interface for stashing.

Comment: I am plenty comfortable with using a command line, I just never have for git. I am very new to it. I have a lot of experience with command line tools, simply not this one. However the tools you've suggested, I'll take a look at them. I do prefer more convenient approaches when they are available.

Comment: To be clear, is this the program you are referring to? http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ (everything about it matches your statement, so I assume so)

Comment: Ok. `git stash` worked - and it allowed me to pull the repository correctly. Now you said to delete `.git\ms-persist.xml`, where should I be finding this file? I closed Visual Studio and do not see it. I am running a search on my system, but I have a REALLY old, pathetic computer (this is a temporary machine, an old Celeron CPU at that, while I wait for new parts to arrive)

Comment: Also, thank you so much for helping with this. It has driven me nuts. You showed me how to fix it, but is it possible for me to ask how this even happened? Do you have any idea why it saw "uncommitted changes" when there in fact were no changes at all?

Comment: @Ciel depends on what will show up as uncommitted. Remember that Git command line is the 'source of truth', when `git status` and Studio give difference results trust the `git`, Studio was built for non-DVCS TFS and even removing readonly flag qualifies as a change, because Windows. It's early days of "native" support for Git in Studio, there are plenty of bugs and missing features but props to them for doing it anyway.

Comment: So the "changes" could be as simple as me even opening up the solution in visual studio. That would actually explain a lot. I wonder if they are aware of this at Microsoft... I'm going to try and find the right place to contact to show this to them and see if this can be looked into.

Comment: @Ciel `.git` is a hidden folder in the root of your project, it what makes it a Git repo rather than a just a folder and contains all the history, hashes, branches, etc. Only delete it `ms-persist.xml` when `git stash` and Studio's explorer say difference things, it means bad things happen and it should force Studio to regenerate it.

Comment: @Ciel if just opening a solution in Studio creates new changes you should review your `.gitignore` file, this generated cruft is user or computer specific and should not be tracked or be part of your repo, the `bin` and `obj` folders, the `.suo` files, etc.

Comment: Thanks again, that is actually a lot of very useful information. I've learned quite a bit just from this small problem alone in a very short span of time.

Comment: So why is this being down voted now ..? It was a legitimate problem, and one that an answer was not readily available for, and we solved it very quickly. I've known a lot of developers with this same issue who were pleased when I directed them to this thread.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up and let you know that I have successfully done this on all of my work environments and it works __beautifully__. This has completely, and absolutely solved my problem. I am learning more about _`git`_ every single day and am finding the tool you linked me instrumental in it. I have also spoken to the appropriate people at __Microsoft__ about these issues, and have been told that many of them will be built right into the next update to _Visual Studio 2013_ or the next CTP of _Visual Studio 2014_, or both.

Comment: In my case, since I am also having the same issue in Visual studio 2015, I used the SourceTree and it works seamlessly.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 they made the handling worse. There are no splits to "included changes", "excluded changes" and "untracked files". I could only fix this with external tools. F.e. once having local changes in gitignore can no more ignore it via untracked files in VS, I can only undo it and create a gitignore each time, or check it in and have this faults over and over again. Wonder who is that stupid at MS to allow this change in first place - now they have this annoying bug and no way out of it without using external tools. Also the commit-view is a total mess now!